# Clustered standard errors in linear regression

Tags: r

Newbie question: I am currently writing my thesis about the impact of an analysis tool on the number of fans for a company. I created the following regression model: `Fans ~ eventWeek * analysistool`

The problem with this function is that it assumes that every line in the data is unrelated, which it is not. Therefore, my thesis coach advised me to use clustered standard errors within R and cluster it on Company Number. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this document](http://dynaman.net/R/clrob.pdf) answers your question in terms of GLMs.

Comment: Link is broken.